# Inequality $(1-e^x)\ln(1-xe^{-x})\leq x^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality

This inequality, which appears to hold for all $x\in\Bbb R$,$$(1-e^x)\ln(1-xe^{-x})\leq x^2$$ arose when I [tried to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4496227/471884) that the positive root of $x-\frac{x^2}{a}-\log(x+1)$ is bounded above by $a-\log(a+1)$.

Note that for the question linked, it suffices to prove the inequality for $x>0$, but I found it holds for $x<0$ too. The LHS is neither even nor odd so we will need to consider each case separately.

Near zero, the bound is very tight; for example, expressing the inequality as an integral $$\int_0^x\left(1-3t-\frac{(t-1)^2}{e^t-t}-e^t \ln\left(1-t e^{-t}\right)\right)\,dt<0$$ fails since both $1-3t-\frac{(t-1)^2}{(e^t-t)}$ and $e^t\ln(1-te^{-t})$ are strictly decreasing.

Can the inequality be analytically proven?

Comment: is it log based $10$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame It is base $e$

Comment: so $\ln$ then ?

Comment: Show $e^{x^2}> (1-xe^{-x})^{1-e^x}$ for $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Where the LHS tends to $\infty$ as $x \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: Just a small thing, but it should be $\le$ because both sides are $0$ when $x=0$. Have you tried using the series expansion of $\ln(1-x)$? That might be helpful.

Comment: @VarunVejalla good point, the Taylor series expansion of $\ln$ might be of use here. I thought it was enough to show $e^{x^2}> (1-xe^{-x})^{1-e^x}$

Comment: @HossienSahebjame That’d be enough, but it’s pretty much the same as the original problem (in fact, I’d argue that it’s harder to work with).

Comment: couldn't you show as $x \rightarrow \infty$ it holds and if $x \rightarrow -\infty$ since in both cases the LHS tends to $\infty$ @VarunVejalla

Comment: @VarunVejalla could you upvote my solution in that case, somebody downvoted it.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it's true in the middle though. As a counter-example, consider $x^2$ and $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. In the limits, $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}<x^2$, but it's not true for $x$ around $0$.

Comment: sorry meant $\geq$ @VarunVejalla

Comment: I'd guess the "true near $\pm\infty$" idea is completable by a rather tedious taylor's theorem estimate near $x=0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sketch of a proof**:

We split into three cases.

**Case 1**: $x = 0$

The desired inequality is clearly true.

**Case 2**: $x \le 1$ and $x \ne 0$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{-x}{1 - \mathrm{e}^x} \ge \frac{\ln(1 - x \mathrm{e}^{-x})}{-x}.$$

We use the Tangent Line (TL) trick.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{-x}{1 - \mathrm{e}^x} \ge 1 - \frac{x}{2} \tag{1}$$
and
$$1 - \frac{x}{2} \ge \frac{\ln(1 - x \mathrm{e}^{-x})}{-x}. \tag{2}$$

The proofs of (1) and (2) are not difficult.

**Case 3**: $x > 1$

Using $u \ge \ln(1 + u)$ for all $u > -1$, we let $u = \frac{1}{1 - x\mathrm{e}^{-x}} - 1$ to get
$$-\ln (1 - x\mathrm{e}^{-x}) \le \frac{x\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1 - x\mathrm{e}^{-x}}.$$

Since $\mathrm{e}^x - 1 > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$(\mathrm{e}^x - 1) \cdot \frac{x\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{1 - x\mathrm{e}^{-x}}
\le x^2$$
or
$$\frac{x(x - 1)(\mathrm{e}^x - 1 - x)}{\mathrm{e}^x - x} \ge 0$$
which is true (using $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

We define: $$f(x)=\ln(1-xe^{-x})-\frac{x^2}{1-e^x}$$

$f(0)=0$, Consider $x>0$

$$f'(x)=\frac{(e^x-1-x)(1-2x-e^x(1-3x+x^2))}{(e^x-1)^2(e^x-x)}$$

$$e^x-1-x>0,~~~e^x-x>0,~~~(e^x-1)^2>0$$

So the sign of $f'(x)$ only depends on the sign of $~g(x)=(1-2x-e^x(1-3x+x^2))$

$g(0)=0$, $g(\epsilon^+)>0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\to-\infty$

We can show $g(x)$ has only one positive root, namely $g(r)=0$. I put this proof in the very end.

Therefore, $g(x)$ is positive on $(0,r)$ and goes to negative on $(r,\infty)$

So $f(x)$ first increases till $x=r$ to reach the maxima, then goes decreasingly forever. Also asymptotically, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$, and this asymptotic limit guarantees $f(x)$ stays always above x-axis.

Because assume at some $x_p$, $f(x_p)<0$, since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$, which means when $x$ is sufficiently large, we can find some $x_s$, such that $x_p<x_s$, but $f(x_p)<f(x_s)<0$. This contradicts with the fact that $f(x)$ decreases forever on $(r,\infty)$. Therefore, $f(x)$ asymptotically goes to  $0$ and always stays above x-axis.

From all above, $f(x)$ is positive on $(0,\infty)$.

--------**Appendix**--------

In this section, we want to show there is only one positive root for $g(x)=0$

Assume the opposite is true, where $g(x)$ has at least two distinct positive roots. Let $x_1$ be the first positive root. Two cases:

Case $(1)$: $g(x_1)=0$ and $g'(x_1)=0$

In this case, $x_1$ is the touching point with x-axis. So we have $g(x_1+\epsilon)>0$. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\to-\infty$, there is at least another root $x_2$. So we have $g(0)=g(x_1)=g(x_2)=0$, where $x_1<x_2$. By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $t_1\in(0,x_1)$ and $t_2\in(x_1,x_2)$, such that $g'(t_1)=g'(t_2)=0$. Together with $g'(x_1)=0$, $t_1<x_1<t_2$, we have three distinct positive roots for $g'(x)=0$.

Again, by Mean Value Theorem, there are two distinct positive roots for $g''(x)=0$. But $g''(x)=-e^x(x^2+x-3)$, only one positive root. So we get contradiction for Case $(1)$.

Case $(2)$: $g(x_1)=0$ and $g(x_1+\epsilon)<0$

Case $(2.a)$: the next root $x_2$ (which is the closest to $x_1$) is a touching point to x-axis, namely $g'(x_2)=0$. By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $t_1\in(0,x_1)$ and $t_2\in(x_1,x_2)$, such that $g'(t_1)=g'(t_2)=0$. Together with $g'(x_2)=0$, then we have three distinct positive roots for $g'(x)=0$, hence two distinct positive roots for $g''(x)=0$, which goes back to the similar contradiction in Case $(1)$.

Case $(2.b)$: the next root $x_2$, where $g(x_2)=0$ and $g(x_2+\epsilon)>0$. Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)\to-\infty$, there exists at least another root $x_3$, such that $g(x_3)=0$, where $x_2<x_3$. So we have at least $g(0)=g(x_1)=g(x_2)=g(x_3)=0$, $\Rightarrow$ three distinct positive roots for $g'(x)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ two distinct positive roots for $g''(x)=0$, so we get similar contradiction as in Case.$(1)$

In conclusion, there is only one positive root for $g(x=r)=0$.

Comment: How can we show that $g(x)$ does not have more than one positive root?

Comment: How can we show that $f(x)$ is negative on $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: I will add that part later @Dan

Comment: Have added @Dan

Comment: Woludn't $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$ be better than $ f(0)=0 $ as $x=0$ is not in domain

Comment: @MathFail Thanks. I think we can abbreviate your explanation of why $g(x)$ has at most one positive root, as follows: $g'(0)=0$ and $g'(x)$ has exactly one positive stationary point, so $g'(x)$ has at most one positive root, and since $g(0)=0$, $g(x)$ has at most one positive root.

Comment: @MathFail We can prove $g(x)$ has no negative root: $g''(0)=3>0$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=\infty$, so if $g(x)$ has a negative root then $g''(x)$ must have at least two negative roots, but $g''(x)$ has only one negative root. $\therefore g(x)$ has no negative root. So for $x<0$ we have $f'(x)>0$, and (since $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=0$) therefore  $f(x)<0$. Combine this comment with your answer, and the question is settled.